# get background image name using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a background image for a div, I would like to get the background image name alone using jquery.

i am getting 'http://localhost/xampp/uconnect/images/tour-networks-ss.png'

but i need only 'tour-networks-ss.png'

please help me in this

Answer (score 11):

there are many ways to achieve maybe `.split()` is the shortest :)

```
splitted = url.split('/');
filename = splitted[splitted.length -1]
```

**edit:** it event can be done on one row:

```
image = url.split('/').pop();
```

Comment: And you don't even need jquery!

Comment: Please do so with the spell-check on. No offense Tenef.  :-)

Comment: But if you would like to use a jQuery selector: the slice() on the end was added to remove the closing parenthesis $('body').css('background-image').split('/').pop().slice(0, -1);